# SQLZoo Hard Questions: Get results that share an ID on the same row

Tags: sql

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/AdventureWorks_hard_questions

Question 11 states:

> For every customer with a 'Main Office' in Dallas show AddressLine1 of the 'Main Office' and AddressLine1 of the 'Shipping' address - if there is no shipping address leave it blank. Use one row per customer.

Relevant Tables/IDs are:

```
Customer             CustomerAddress              Address
Customer ID          CustomerID                   AddressID
                     AddressID                    AddressLine1
                     AddressType                  City
```

My current code is

```
SELECT CA.CustomerID, 
CASE WHEN CA.AddressType = 'Main Office' THEN A.AddressLine1 ELSE "" END, .
CASE WHEN CA.AddressType = 'Shipping' THEN A2.AddressLine1 ELSE "" END 
FROM Address A
JOIN CustomerAddress CA 
ON A.AddressID = CA.AddressID 
JOIN Address A2 
ON A.AddressID = A2.AddressID
WHERE A.City = 'Dallas'
```

There's 5 total main offices in Dallas, and only one has a shipping address.

When I tried to "Group By CustomerID" it only returns one of the addresses, even if I've searched for both of them like in the query above.

How do I get BOTH addresses to return on the same row?

Comment: Is this for Sql Server?

Comment: Sure. I'm essentially learning half in Server and half in MySQL, so either one works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 weeks later, I've finally figured it out.

```
SELECT T0.MainAddress AS 'Main Address', 
       isnull(T1.ShippingAddress,' ') AS 'Shipping Address'
FROM (SELECT CA.CustomerID AS [CustomerID], A.AddressLine1 AS [MainAddress]
      FROM CustomerAddress CA
      INNER JOIN Address A 
          ON A.AddressID = CA.AddressID
      WHERE CA.AddressType = 'Main Office' 
          AND A.City = 'Dallas') T0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CA.CustomerID AS [CustomerID], 
                  A.AddressLine1 AS [ShippingAddress]
           FROM CustomerAddress CA 
           INNER JOIN Address A
               ON A.AddressID = CA.AddressID
           WHERE CA.AddressType = 'Shipping'
               AND A.City = 'Dallas') T1 
     ON T0.CustomerID = T1.CustomerID
```

I eventually had to just make two different tables to draw from, as opposed to trying to draw from existing data. It's similar to the answer above, but it actually functions in the website that I was working in.

Answer (score 2):

First in cte you filter customers from Dallas. Then left joining to find their shipping addresses:

```
;with cte as(select ca.customerid, a.addressline1
             from customeraddress ca 
             join address a on ca.addressid = a.addressid
             where ca.addresstype = 'Main Office' and a.City = 'Dallas') 
select c.customerid,
       c.addressline1 as mainaddress,
       a.addressline1 as shippingaddress
from cte c
left join customeraddress ca on c.customerid = ca.customerid and 
                                ca.addresstype = 'Shipping'
left join address a on ca.addressid = a.addressid
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach to use aggregate function with GROPING.

```
    SELECT Cust.CustomerID
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN CustAddr.AddressType = 'Main Office' THEN Addr.AddressLine1 ELSE NULL END) as 'MainOffice'
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN CustAddr.AddressType = 'Shipping' THEN Addr.AddressLine1 ELSE NULL END) as 'Shipping'
    FROM  Customer as Cust INNER JOIN CustomerAddress as CustAddr ON (Cust.CustomerID = CustAddr.CustomerID)
                           INNER JOIN Address as Addr ON (Addr.AddressID = CustAddr.AddressID)
WHERE Addr.City = 'Dallas'
GROUP BY Cust.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer didn't require checking for nulls:

```
SELECT MainOfficeAd, ShippingAd 
FROM (SELECT customerid, addressline1 as MainOfficeAd 
    FROM customeraddress
    JOIN Address ON(customeraddress.addressid=address.addressid)
    WHERE AddressType='Main Office' AND city='Dallas') ma 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT customerid, addressline1 as ShippingAD 
    FROM customeraddress 
    JOIN Address ON(customeraddress.addressid=address.addressid)
    WHERE AddressType='Shipping' AND city='Dallas') sa 
ON (ma.customerid=sa.customerid);
```